# How do I create a columnrange highchart with a point object (consisting of one x and two y values)?

Tags: charts, highcharts, range

How can I create a columnrange highchart with a point object with one x and two y values? I need to have a point object as the points should be clickable and styleable.

Is there something like

```
data: [
   {x:1, y1:-5.2, y2:10.4}
]
```

or

```
data: [
   {x:2, y: [-13.5, 9.8]}
]
```

I already tried these and some other things but they didn't work.

Is there any way to create something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Put up an example on jsfiddle.net and we can play around with it

Comment: Here is a fiddle example. I just cannot work with categories in my example... this is the challenge ;-) http://jsfiddle.net/paranoir/FG82J/1/

Comment: What is the second y represent?

Comment: The first y value represents a low value and the second y value a high value of a range object. The x is the time in this case.

Comment: xAxis already represent the date or time, and data {x,y} already represent min and max, too.

Comment: Yes and no. I cannot work with categories, so I need to put the time (seconds) as the x value and the low value as y1 (or y_low) and the high value as y2 (or y_high)... therefore I need these 3 'points' to display the data.

Comment: If I would use 'column' (or another non-range series type) as the series type, the data would be interpreted as [x,y]. I already do that in another chart. What I need now is [x, y_low, y_high]. Like that: http://jsfiddle.net/paranoir/FG82J/6/ Only as an object and not as an array.

Comment: The Point object in highcharts has only one x and one y value which both can be numbers: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezS3b/

Comment: Yes, that would be the solution if I would have regular time intervals. Sorry, I didn't mention this before. The time intervals I have are irregular. Like in this [Highcharts Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/type-datetime-irregular/)

Comment: +1. good question, and I learned new thing about highcharts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of y1/y2 you should use low/high

```
{
                x:Date.UTC(2012,12,2),
                low:-9.7, 
                high:9.4
},
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! **Thanks a lot!** It might be helpful to put that in the API doc as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: [
    [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),-9.7, 9.4],
    [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2),-8.7, 6.5],
    [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3),-3.5, 9.4],
    [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6),-1.4, 19.9],
    [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7),0.0, 22.6],
    [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8),2.9, 29.5],
]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezS3b/1/)